# Creating a fixed table in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, html-table, survey, qualtrics

Basically, I want to create a table in Qualtrics (part of the instructions for a survey) that will stay fixed on the page and scroll with the participant as the move down the page through a long series of questions (and yes, I'm unable to do repeated headers because of the nature of the table/instructions and how the question is formatted). I found this JavaScript code:

```
var box = document.createElement('div');
box.style.position = 'fixed';
box.style.top = '100px';
box.style.right = '10px';
box.style.width = '200px';
box.style.height = '100px';
box.style.color = 'black';
box.style.background = 'lightblue';
box.style.padding = '20px';
box.innerText = 'Hello world';
document.body.appendChild(box);
```

that worked exactly as it should. But I need to take this code and apply it to a table that would look like this:

[image: 2x2 table shown here]

I need this without the empty middle cell, that was mainly to help keep it centered but having it fixed would do that just as well. However, my knowledge of JavaScript is limited.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- The solution is already specified in the Question Post, the only missing piece is replacing "Hello world" plain text with HTML markup suitable to render a table.
- The missing piece can be accomplished by inserting a non-displaying HTML table inside the HTML, then extracting the OuterHTML of that region and doing a string.replace on the attribute `display:none;` to change it to `display:inline;`

### Example

#### Additional HTML

- generic html table different from OP 2x2 example, modify as needed

```
  <table id="uu838localtable1596993593" style="display:none;">
    <tr><th>Label</th><th>Value</th></tr>
    <tr><td>fname</td><td>Huomer</td></tr>
    <tr><td>lname</td><td>Huimpson</td></tr>
    <tr><td>age</td><td>33</td></tr>
  </table>
```

#### Modified Javascript

```
      var box = document.createElement('div');
      box.style.position    = 'fixed';
      box.style.top         = '10px';
      box.style.right       = '10px';
      box.style.width       = '500px';
      box.style.height      = '200px';
      box.style.color       = 'black';
      box.style.border      = '2px solid #0e0e0e';
      box.style.background  = 'lightblue';
      box.style.padding     = '20px';
      boxContent            =   (document.getElementById("uu838localtable1596993593").outerHTML);
      boxContent            =   boxContent.replace("display:none", "display:inline");
      box.innerHTML         =   boxContent;
      document.body.appendChild(box);
```

Comment: I had a follow up question to this. I've used this code and it works perfects, but I want this element centered on the page it's shown on. How would I adjust the style options fo make this happen?